# Print a bitmap image without resizing through Wi-Fi on Android App?

Tags: android, printing, qr-code, barcode-printing, android-print-framework

I need to make an app for label printing like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ei2b01wtNqc)

I am checking [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/printing/photos.html)

And [PrintHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/print/PrintHelper.html) has very simple and limited features.

1. I can only use two scales - `SCALE_MODE_FILL`, `SCALE_MODE_FIT`.
   My bitmap image has a size of 512px X 512px. And I might need to adjust the size because of the label sticker size.
   OR I need to choose the size of paper(ex. 100mm X 100mm) then, both way above will have the same result.
2. When I try this code, It opens print setting activity.

```
    private void doPhotoPrint(Bitmap bitmap) {
        PrintHelper printHelper = new PrintHelper(this);
        printHelper.setColorMode(COLOR_MODE_MONOCHROME);
//        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.droids);
        printHelper.printBitmap("droids.jpg - test print", bitmap);
    }
```

However, I just want to implement the print function without opening the setting screen, But just when I click 'print' on my application, then right away print `one or more bitmap images continuously` with the default settings that I set(image size, black&white/color, printer that is connected, paper size).

Is there any way to make a function like [the video above](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ei2b01wtNqc)?

Answer (score 1):

With the `PrintHelper` you get the system print dialog there is no way to print silently as the user has to pick the printer and the print attributes from the dialog. To function like the video, you'd need to implement the discovery and printing functionalities with the printer directly

Comment: Yes, is that possible with `PrintHelper`? I'd like to connect it directly. It'd be great if you give me more info with simple code.